# MS ACCESS EXPRESSIONS

Tags: ms-access

Just a quick question regarding conditional formatting/Expressions. I have a form which holds information (Invoice Date, Payment terms, Payment Due, Days Left, and Paid).

Payment due adds 30 days on to the Invoice date and Days left shows us how many days left that it has.

My question is how can I make it so that when the tick box "Paid" is ticked then it sets the Days Left to 0 or Blank. rather than continuously counting down.

[image]

Comment: Edit question to show expression for the DaysLeft calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use an IIf() to conditionally adjust DaysLeft based on value of checkbox.

`=IIf([Paid], 0, days left calc here)`

Comment: Hi, What would the calc here be?

Comment: "IIf([Check139]=0,"0","")" I have tried this and it works to show the false part, but when the paid check box is pressed it says "#type!" I have even tried changing the code to "IIf([Check139]=0,0,"")"

Comment: 'calc here' would be whatever calculation you are doing to calculate the days left. You did not post that in your question. My guess is that would be difference between current date and due date.